# Internal server error in go daddy in web api application

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am facing a problem i need some help.Problem is that i publish a web application in Godaddy server it is giving internal server error while it is working fine in visual studio and when i go in details of the error it giving fallowing message

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Prasadseed.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +0

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +10103347
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +123
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +181
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +228
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +314

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10083568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0
```

Comment: Read the error message. Now interpret it and then see what is missing on the server.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the solution. Then ensure that all the DLLs referenced by your application (those in the bin folder) are deployed to your hosting provider. The error is self-explanatory - you are missing a DLL on the application.

Comment: It is possible there are more than one versions of this dll in different projects. Code may not throw error while compiling but it will throw error at runtime.

Comment: @Angelo i have done this but i am facing same error message

Comment: @fluidguid then how to rid from it

Comment: Sometimes, nuget pakcage manager shows if you have mismatch version of dlls (if they were installed using nuget).  Go to "Manage nuget packages for solution..." --> "Consolidate".  This tab will tell you all mismatch versions.
However, if the mismatch is not due to nuget, then you will need to compare dll versions manually. You can also try changing registry as the error message suggests, but I have never tried that, so I cannot speak for it. In short, you will need to match correct versions of the dll, whether that is System.Web.Http or its dependency.

Comment: Can you provide a listing of your nuget packages (package.json)?